# I am getting an error when I run a command with my discord bot

Tags: discord.js, minecraft

I am using [this][1] Minecraft server util and I am getting the following error. Is there anyway I can fix this error?

Please note that the error is not when the bot is run its when the command -rcon is run.

This is my code for the command handler, and the command. This is attempting to run the command "list" using rcon.

Code: https://pastebin.com/QWysjvnu

If there is a better way I can be running commands through discord please let me know.

````
        client.commands.get('rcon').execute(message, args, server);
                                   ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'execute' of undefined
    at Client.<anonymous> (/Users/myname/Downloads/Esentrix Bot/main.js:47:36)
    at Client.emit (events.js:376:20)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (/Users/myname/Downloads/Esentrix Bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (/Users/myname/Downloads/Esentrix Bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/Users/myname/Downloads/Esentrix Bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/Users/myname/Downloads/Esentrix Bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/Users/myname/Downloads/Esentrix Bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/Users/myname/Downloads/Esentrix Bot/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:132:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:376:20)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (/Users/myname/Downloads/Esentrix Bot/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:835:20)```

------RCON Command-------
module.exports = {
    name: 'mcstats',
    description: "This command runs commands in Esentrix via rcon!",
    execute(message, args){
        const util = require('minecraft-server-util');
 
        const client = new util.RCON('esentrixmc.plox.vip', { port: 25575, enableSRV: true, timeout: 5000, password: 'my password here' }); // These are the default options
        
        client.on('output', (message) => {
            console.log(message);
        
            // The client must be closed AFTER receiving the message.
            // Closing too early will cause the client to never output
            // any message.
            client.close();
        });
        
        client.connect()
            .then(() => client.run('list')) // List all players online
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    }
}

  [1]: https://github.com/PassTheMayo/minecraft-server-util
````

Comment: Can you edit your command file into your question

Comment: My command file is in the pastebin but sure.

Comment: It's best for everyone to have it as text, not a link or image

Comment: Done. Ok Thanks, I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: Why do you have `module.exports.execute` instead of `module.exports`?

Comment: Oh I meant to remove that, I was testing something, it still gives the same error without that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue #1**: You're nesting your module into a parent element named `execute`, your module will not be found this way.

**Issue #2**: Your module has a name of `'mcstats'`, not `rcron`. Use the correct name.

Main File:

```
client.commands.get('mcstats').execute(message, args, server);
```

Command File:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'mcstats',
    description: "This command runs commands in Esentrix via rcon!",
    execute(message, args){
        const util = require('minecraft-server-util');
 
        const client = new util.RCON('esentrixmc.plox.vip', { port: 25575, enableSRV: true, timeout: 5000, password: 'my password here' }); // These are the default options
        
        client.on('output', (message) => {
            console.log(message);
        
            // The client must be closed AFTER receiving the message.
            // Closing too early will cause the client to never output
            // any message.
            client.close();
        });
        
        client.connect()
            .then(() => client.run('list')) // List all players online
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: I now get ```ReferenceError: server is not defined```. When I added server to the command handler. I also switched the command over the -mcstats, because that what it should do at the end.